# Axios.put ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

It's kinda working,but problem is it copies the file which is being updated and puts it in the end of page,All I'm trying to do display update on the item

Here what I'm trying to do

```
    submitEdit = (id, value) => {
    let {todos} = this.state
    todos.map((item => {
        if (item._id === id) {
            axios
                .put(`http://localhost:8080/edit/${id}`, {
                    todo: value,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        todos:[...todos,{todo:value}]
                    })
                    console.log("res", res);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("err", err);
                });
        }
    }))
}
```

beside this everything is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the state by using the index so that the todo element is updated and not copied and added to the end

You can use `Array.prototype.slice` with `spread syntax` to do that

```js
todos.map(((item, i) => {
    if (item._id === id) {
        axios
            .put(`http://localhost:8080/edit/${id}`, {
                todo: value,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    todos:[...todos.slice(0, i),{todo:value}, ...todos.slice(i + 1)]
                })
                console.log("res", res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err", err);
            });
    }
}))
```

Comment: Oh my god,Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for a long time!

Comment: Um, i have another problem,when I'm trying to edit item which i already editted,function is not working at all